# Design applications with dynamic data

Tags: android, performance

if the application receives its data from remote server then we should save our data in the local database and have our UI load data from the local database for better UX right? Our UI should not load data from servers directly it will result in bad UX. Now my question is I am developing an e-commerce application and it’s data is very dynamic it can change anytime. The product can go out of stock, it’s price and the discount amount can change etc. So how to keep up with it. If I refresh local database every time user opens application then what will be the benefit of the local database. If any of you had faced the similar situation or worked on any e-commerce applications then please me suggest me better ways. Any help would be appreciated. I do not know if this is a right platform to ask this questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions. You can use push notifications using Parse, for instance, when your MySQL changes. Or you can use JobManager to enqueue custom synchronization tasks. I recommend you to see this video and check out the video project: https://github.com/yigit/dev-summit-architecture-demo

This reflects your problem very good and it is a very nice solution and, the most important, it is developed by a Google employee.

I hope it helps you!